# Select only if count==2 SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i would like to select only on the condition that another select == 2

for example

```
select field1 from table1 where count((select field2 from table2)) = 2
```

is this possible?

Comment: There's no relationship between table1.field1 and table2.field2 listed in your question...

Comment: Everyone is clamoring at answers in which they assume what you are trying to do. The short answer is NO. **However**, we can suggest something if we knew what you are attempting.

Comment: can you clarify your goal with this?  Basing a select in table 1 based on a count of another table with no relationship is nonsensical on the surface...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the [`HAVING CLAUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) of SQL's `GROUP BY`.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE <MYKEY> IN (
   SELECT <MYKEY>
   FROM TABLE2
   GROUP BY <MYKEY> HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 --Better to use > 1
)
```

Comment: I went away to code it in my sql server and when I came back you had posted mine already! haha

Comment: You're assuming that the OP wants a count of rows in `table2`. IMHO, that's unfounded.

Comment: @Brad: Look at the title of the post, this is how I have pretty good idea of what he is after. Why don't you quit with all the down voting.

Comment: @Brad said `You're assuming that the OP wants a count of rows in table2. IMHO, that's unfounded.` The OP isn't clear about what they want, and the code they give does not work, but appears to attempt to count the rows in table2.  However, the OP is using two tables, but the code here only uses one.  I'd like to see a working example of this.  I can see how GROUP BY - HAVING could work for this.

Comment: @KM: I've updated my response with a two table example. You can use multiple columns in the `GROUP BY <MYKEY> HAVING` part of the query if you need to as well.

Comment: I'm going to start sounding like Brad now, but that is an interesting interpretation of the question.  I don't read the question that way, but it may be what they are after.  I'll bet the OP abandons this question, never leaving any indication of what they were after.

Answer (score 2):

```
select field1 from table1 where (select count(field2) from table2)=2
```

Comment: This will work, but you're assuming what the OP wants. Also, this returns either all rows in `table1` if `table2` has exactly two rows, or it returns nothing.

Comment: You're assuming what the OP wants. Too risky.

Comment: @Brad said `You're assuming what the OP wants. Too risky.` The OP isn't clear about what they want, and the code they give does not work, but appears to attempt to count the rows in table2.

Answer (score 1):

try it out:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @a table (RowID int)
insert @a values(1);insert @a values(2);insert @a values(3);
declare @b table (RowID int)
insert @b values(10);insert @b values(20)
SET NOCOUNT OFF

select a.RowID FROM @a a WHERE 2=(SELECT COUNT(RowID) FROM @b)

delete @b where RowID=20

select a.RowID FROM @a a WHERE 2=(SELECT COUNT(RowID) FROM @b)
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowID
-----------
1
2
3

(3 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

RowID
-----------
```

(0 row(s) affected)